# Grabbing all instances of anything between { these two } characters PHP

Tags: php

I am creating a system where there will be {these tags, with stuff in}
at various levels of the document.

How can i obtain the contents effectively?

Example:

```
   // this is a php/html doc.
    {variablename} <<< how can i grab all instances like this, then do something?
```

Essentially taking a file, and replacing all instances of the tags with the right output and then returning the file. This is my task.

Comment: Using regex? Or just `str_replace` if you only want to replace them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using regular expressions:

```
$s = 'this is some {text} and {more}';
$p = "/{(.*)}/U";
preg_match_all($p,$s,$m);
var_dump($m);
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "{text}"
    [1]=>
    string(6) "{more}"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "text"
    [1]=>
    string(4) "more"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

str_replace will work for fixed (known) variables. To catch any value within {} you'll have to use regular expressions.

```
$content = "lorem ipsum {something} dolor sit amet.";

$content = str_replace( "{something}", "something else", $content );

echo( $content );

// echos: lorem ipsum something else dolor sit amet.
```